# Loadrunner asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, session, loadrunner

We have an asp.net 3.5 web app that we must start load testing with LoadRunner

What we have found is that if you open several browsers (ie8) they share the same session id, so making a change in one window impacts the other windows (not just our app, others app also).

Now, LoadRunner can simulate a number of users per pc, and so we are finding its getting messed up since its all sharing the same session.

Any ideas on what is the best method to prevent this (we don't want to go with cookieless sessions).

How would you ensure each browser window is treated as a unique session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 'Feature' of IE8 :-S.

You can however start IE in a "start with new session" mode though. use:

```
iexplore.exe -nomerge
```

Not to sure how this would be applied to LoadRuner though (Never worked with it)

Comment: Does anyone know if you can direct browsers to operate in this mode from the server? Of course we would need to get all browser types and versions so this is proably a non runner

Answer (score 0):

session/state is unique to a single user, but not across users.   You will need to correlate both session and state data across your scripts and then you should be able to execute mutiple users on a single load generator without issue

Whether a new browser session is opened is purely a client side issue.  The server does not know or care that a different browser session has been instantiated and is only responding to a valid request as indicated by session token, security token, state token, etc...

Answer (score 0):

While replaying scripts in loadrunner, it doesnt invoke the IE and it wont have impact of the tabs.

Use the setting Check for newer versions of the stored pages every visit will help on this issue.

Also you can put clear cache and cookies before each iteration.so that each time new sessions will be created.